# Automatically adjust column width in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am not that much good in designs and I have a design issue which is dragging me for hours. If anyone can help me on that would be appreciable.

I have a `div` with a `.container` class and inside that, we have three div's. One with a class `.col-md-3` another with a class `.col-md-6` and the third one with class `.col-md-3`. The third column shouldn't be there at all. In some cases, it only the first and second `div` will be there.

Can we make the second `div` taken the space of third one if it is not there ? Is there any method in bootstrap for this.

Please help me.

Comment: Which version of bootstrap

Comment: The version is Bootstrap 3

Comment: Upgrade to Bootstrap 4, then the answer is "yes, you can do that.": http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: Using bootstrap4, you can do it

Comment: can you provide your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `col` classes to `div`. it will automatically adjust if one div is removed from the `row`

check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#equal-width for more information

```css
.col {
  background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
    border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can check by removing one column from the row

Answer (score 1):

You heck a little but on bootstrap 3. by adding some of custom CSS.

> **Please View in full page mode**

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#toggle_col').toggle();
});
```

```css
.col-sm-3 {
  background-color: red;
}

.col-sm-6 {
  background-color: blue;
}

/* this will do the trick */

@media (min-width: 768px)
  .flex-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}

.flex-col {
 flex: 1 0 auto;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<div class="row flex-row">
 <div class="col-sm-3">3</div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 flex-col">6</div>
 <div class="col-sm-3" id="toggle_col">3</div>
 </div>
</div>

<button>Toggle Column</button>
```